# pass php global variable into ajax.success()

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have some ajax code:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/ajax/createOrder.php",
  type: "POST",
  cache: false,
  data: {
    "nameSelf": nameSelf,
    "phoneSelf": phoneSelf,
    "email": email,
    "delivery": delivery
  },
  dataType: "html",
  success: function(data) {
    -- -- -- -- -- -- > $("#orderConfirmationDescription").html("<?php $userOrderId ?>");
  }
});
```

How i should i pass global `$userOrderId` into my element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `echo` in your PHP, and remove double quotes.

```
$("#orderConfirmationDescription").html(<?php echo $userOrderId; ?>);
```